# cv2 python has no imread member

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I pip installed OpenCV-python. The installation seems to be fine and I tested it out on the python IDLE. It ran without any problems. I've been trying to run it on VS Code but it doesn't seem to work. The autocomplete recognizes the imread function but when I type it in it throws up an error saying cv2 has no imread member. I am using the most updated version of python

I am calling it like this:`img2 = cv2.imread("C:\Biometric\min.jpg", 0)`

Comment: But the import cv2 command went through successfully?

Comment: It didn't have any errors

Comment: Ensure that IDLE and VS Code are looking at the same instance on python on your computer. This is just on the off-chance you have a package called cv2 in the VS Code Python instance that has nothing do with opencv

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since you are trying to executing this with VS Code, try following steps

1. Open palette on VS Code (use specifies command): CTRL + Shift + P
2. Then select "Preferences > Open Settings (JSON)" option in the palette dropdown
3. Then add the following line in the opened `settings.json` file
   `python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]`

this must work

Comment: This stopped pylint from working altogether for me. I had to change `"--generated-members"` to `"--generated-members=cv2.*"` (see answer below)

Comment: Suggested solution is depreciated, use:
`"pylint.args": ["--generated-members=cv2.*"]`

Answer (score 47):

I tried so many hacks. They were not working. Someone suggested:

```
from cv2 import cv2
```

I think this is the best solution to this problem

Comment: @VibhorDube Well it's a linter problem and not the code, so that's probably why the other question is accepted.

Answer (score 11):

### Solution 1: Change pylint settings

1. Open the Command Palette from menu "View" or by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Type "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and hit enter to open the settings.json file
3. In the block surrounded by curly braces add a comma to the last line and then add the line

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members=cv2.*"]
```

4. Save using the menu "File" or by pressing Ctrl + S
5. Go back to your python file and convince yourself that "cv2" is no longer flagged by the    linter but all other types of errors are still detected

### Solution 2: Use a different linter

1. Open the Command Palette from menu "View" or by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Type "Python: Select Linter" and hit enter
3. Select a different linter, e.g. flake8.
   For a comparison of different linters check out https://realpython.com/python-code-quality/

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Shift + P -> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
Then add the following:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i allow myself to give an answer to this question because i had the same problem and only the following method worked for me:

1. Go to pylint extension sittings and find the [Pylint args in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0oTc.png)
2. clic on the blue button and ad cv2 in the space

In fact it's the same thig that adding:

```
    "pylint.args": [
    "cv2"
    ]
```

in the settings.json between the {} (don't forget to ad a comma after the previous element)

Comment: this is invalid argument, that's make pylint server stopped working.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the terminal and type `pylint --extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2`

it has worked for me.

Answer (score -5):

try by putting:

```
**from cv2 import cv2**
```

this will surely work

Comment: It has been already answered above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325592/8374890